# PySpark - create column based on column names referenced in another column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am quite new to spark and can't get it to work... Hopefully, there is an easy way of doing this...
What I am trying to do is best described by the following table: (I need to get the "required" column)

```
    colA    colB    colC    ref     required
1   a1        b1    c1      colA     a1
2   a2        b2    c2      colA     a2
3   a3        b3    c3      colB     b3
4   a4        b4    c4      colB     b4
5   a5        b5    c5      colC     c5
6   a6        b6    c6      colC     c6
```

The above is just an example - in the real example I have >50 columns, so doing conditions is not going to work...

I know this can be easily done in pandas using something like:

```
df['required'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.ref], axis=1)
```

or

```
df['required'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.ref)
```

Any suggestions how to do this in PySpark?

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this is to use `when` and `coalesce` functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cols = ['colA', 'colB', 'colC']
df.withColumn('required', F.coalesce(*[F.when(df.ref == c, df[c]) for c in cols])).show()
+----+----+----+----+--------+
|colA|colB|colC| ref|required|
+----+----+----+----+--------+
|  a1|  b1|  c1|colA|      a1|
|  a2|  b2|  c2|colA|      a2|
|  a3|  b3|  c3|colB|      b3|
|  a4|  b4|  c4|colB|      b4|
|  a5|  b5|  c5|colC|      c5|
|  a6|  b6|  c6|colC|      c6|
+----+----+----+----+--------+
```

Basically you check which column's name the `ref` column is equal to, and take the  value from that column -- `F.when(df.ref == c, df[c])`; This creates a list of column objects whose values are kept when its name appears in the `ref` column, otherwise its values are NULL; Then by coalescing the list of columns, NULL values are filled with values from a valid column values.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!